# Jsf RichFaces autocomplete : get the InputValue for autocomplete- method()

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, autocomplete, richfaces

Part of my xhmtl-Page:

```
<rich:autocomplete autocompleteMethod="#{autocompletMit.searchbyName()}" mode="cachedAjax" 
                           fetchValue="#{controller.mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterName}" autocompleteList="#{autocompletMit.autocompleteList}" minChars="1" autofill="true" var="it" > 
    <h:outputText value="#{it.mitarbeiterName}" style="font-weight:bold"/>  
    </rich:autocomplete>
```

Bean for my Autocomplete:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "autocompletMit")
@RequestScoped
public class AutoCompleteMitarbeiter implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private Transaktionssteuerung transakt;
    private List<String> autocompleteList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String nameSearch;

    public List<String> searchbyName(Object o) {
        String test = (String) o;  
        List<Mitarbeiter> alleMitarbeiter = transakt.alleMitarbeiter();
        for (Iterator<Mitarbeiter> it = alleMitarbeiter.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            if (it.next().getMitarbeiterName().startsWith(test)) {
                autocompleteList.add(it.next().getMitarbeiterName());
            }
        }
            return autocompleteList;
     }
//getter & setter
  }
```

I always get "Unkown property searchbyName" in my .xhtml for `autocompleteMethod="#{autocompletMit.searchbyName()}"` because he excepts a value... Which value do i have to submit here?!?

Comment: I tried some other stuff...

Comment: Have you tried without brackets? `autocompleteMethod="#{autocompletMit.searchbyName}`

Comment: yeah i tried it! i get always SEVERE: Method not found: Controller.AutoCompleteMitarbeiter@7a88716.searchbyName (java.lang.String)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
autocompleteMethod="#{autocompletMit.searchbyName()}"
```

This is not correct when you've a method which takes arguments. Remove those parentheses. The [RichFaces `<rich:autocomplete>` showcase example](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=autocomplete&skin=blueSky) also doesn't show at all that you should be invoking an argumentless method.

---

> *Method not found: Controller.AutoCompleteMitarbeiter@7a88716.searchbyName (java.lang.String)*

It's telling that it expected a `searchbyName` method taking a `String` argument. Yours takes an `Object` argument. This does not match. Fix it accordingly:

```
public List<String> searchbyName(String query) {
```